# Offline support for web application in ipad

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ipad, offline-browsing

I have developed web application for restaurant. Its Front office is developed for iPad and back office maintain .net web application . 
SQL Server 2008 is used as database.

I want to make offline application for Front office which can be used when unable to connect network / DB Server using iPad.

Master table's data cannot be Modified but, there should be latest data of master table to
transaction in other pages.
whenever system is connected to internet all offline transaction should synchronize with online data

It will be better if can suggest me solution without installing sql at client
I have think to use save data  xml/json files as per table structure but its not preferable with large numbers of tables and clients and also security issue is there

Please guide me on this. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: i wasn't aware that, but its increased now

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure: Your frontend is developed using HTML-Technologie?

You could use HTML5 Local Storage and/or offline caching with a manifest.
I think you have to put your data there by hand, but you could write a function for this...